# PayPal IPN postback failure

Tags: paypal, magento-1.5

Earlier I was facing `PayPal IPN postback failure` issue in my Magento store version 1.5.1.0 I am using `Paypal Website Payment standard` method.

I have fixed this issue using link http://www.dhmedia.com.au/article/debugging-paypal-ipn-postback-failures-magento

Now from few days back I started getting same issue again for some paypal orders and it is quite random, for some users it is coming and for others it is working fine.
Also we are using SSL on our store.

What can be the probable issues and how can I track this?

Comment: Check you access.log whether there was a request. And the config of your firewall. I heard about problems with paypal not sending IPNs. Beside of this you should really update. Magento 1.5 has a lot of bugs, especially security bugs!

Comment: @Fabian -- I guess I need to check server access log that was there any response from Paypal or not. Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, I would start there.

Comment: I have checked server logs but there is nothing related to this error. There are no error or exception generated due to paypal.

Comment: I can see PayPal IPN postback failure error only in my Magento Paypal logs.

Comment: if the paypal IPN hits magento it has to be in the accesslog to. But what is in the magento paypal log?

Comment: Update, 1.5 is very dated and your probably running into issues due to this.

Comment: Might be a long shot but try upping your PHP config's max_input_vars from 1000 to 3000.  The default of 1000 can sometimes truncate the IPN response from PayPal.

Comment: What does the PayPal IPN History say? Also you can debug the PayPal IPN response like in the article, and actually step through the code and see what happens. You'll have to bring over the live database (be careful) and simulate an IPN call (I wrote the article).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution to this issue with Paypal IPN is to use this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-paypal-ipn-notification-alerts.html

Ensure to follow the instructions after installation to change your PayPal IPN address to:

```
http://www.YOURSTORENAMEHERE.com/paypalipn/ipnlistener.php
```

in your Paypal settings.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal is currently trying to get all merchants off of PayPal IPN and Website Payments Standard and switch to an API based extension like PayPal Express. You might want to give that a try.